# Countif formula error checking duplicates in cells with formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, countif

This is my google script:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A0zEN4zczP7aYn2aHdFjDxYgDJBi7R3S6NY_MTcM7YA/edit?usp=sharing

How it works:
In my sheet there is plan of production. Column E is only for help to calculate the date from the index used in column C (3M 000 00 0000 is equal to 3M [job_no] [month] [year]). At the top in cell E2 the is MAX fuction which is used to generate next job index with is generated by the script after pressing (+) button.

What I want to get:
Cells in E column calculate data from column C or show value "123456789" if index (3m xxx xx xxxx) in column C is duplicated. I want to get info in cell C2 that "Index 3M xxx xx xxxx is duplicated. Please remove duplicates".

What's the problem:
I use countif function to check for duplicates:
=countif(E5:E;"=123456789")
When I write this function in bar it shows good value (2) but if I click enter it keeps showing 0 in the cell (i8).
The same problem is with vlookup fuction to search the index and name of duplicated values from C column.
I guess the problem is that in E5:E cell have if formulas inside.

Please help me deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect duplicates in column C, use this formula

```
=if(arrayformula(sum(--(if(C8:C="";;countif(left(C8:C;14);left(C8:C;14)))>1)))>0;"Index 3M xxx xx xxxx is duplicated. Please remove duplicates";)
```

and with details ...

```
=if(arrayformula(sum(--(if(C8:C="";;countif(left(C8:C;14);left(C8:C;14)))>1)))>0;"Index """
&textjoin(", ";;unique(query({C8:C\arrayformula(countif(left(C8:C;14);left(C8:C;14)))};"select Col1 where Col1 is not null and Col2>1";0)))&
""" is/are duplicated. Please remove duplicates";)
```

with only the code (14 characters)

```
=if(arrayformula(sum(--(if(C8:C="";;countif(left(C8:C;14);left(C8:C;14)))>1)))>0;"Index """
&textjoin(", ";;unique(query({arrayformula(left(C8:C;14))\arrayformula(countif(left(C8:C;14);left(C8:C;14)))};"select Col1 where Col1 is not null and Col2>1";0)))&
""" is/are duplicated. Please remove duplicates";)
```

[image]

Comment: I works perfectly, but duplicate info is too long for the cell. How to change formula to show only duplicated index (14 letters) further without description of the job?

Comment: i have amended my answer to do so